# after clicking on item from listbox make it again unselected using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have list box as following code:

```
<select onchange="saveQuery(this);" id="savedQuery" size="10" name="savedQuery[]">
  <option value="xyz">XYZ</option>
  <option value="mno">MNO</option>
</select>
```

and function with :

```
 function saveQuery(ptr){
     var queryName;
     var $queryName = $('#savedQuery option:selected').val()
     $("#query").val($queryName);        
 }
```

Here, on change I am getting value of selected item.

I want to unselect it again on same click.
It means select and deselect at a time.

Comment: Deselect how? How bout selecting the first item/option again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get a empty string to value of `$('#savedQuery')` would work.

```
$('#savedQuery').val('');
```

Here is jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/CfDmc/

Comment: Thanx working. But I got other solution $("#savedQuery option:selected").removeAttr("selected", false )

Answer (score 1):

use [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

```
function saveQuery(ptr){
  var queryName;
  var $queryName = $('#savedQuery option:selected').val()
  $("#query").val($queryName);
  $("#savedQuery option:selected").prop("selected", false) ;      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to clear a `select` with jQuery is set it's value to an empty string.

Since you are passing `this` into handler there is no need to create a new search in DOM for `$('#savedQuery')` within the code. Also `$('select').val()` will do same as `$('select option:selected').val()`.

```
function saveQuery(ptr){
     var $this=$(ptr);
     var $queryName = $this.val();
     $("#query").val($queryName);
     /* reset*/
     $this.val('');        
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of following options:

```
$("#savedQuery").val([]);
```

or

```
$("#savedQuery option").prop("selected", false);
```

or

```
$("#savedQuery option:selected").prop("selected", false) ;
```

or

```
$("#savedQuery").find('option').removeAttr("selected");
```

So your function will be like this

```
function saveQuery(ptr){
   var queryName;
   var $queryName = $('#savedQuery option:selected').val()
   $("#query").val($queryName);
   $("#savedQuery").val([]);
}
```